# getBBox().width and height returns 0

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am getting width and height of text by `getBBox()` in `SVG`. There is two buttons in my application, when I click `button1` it will display `button2` and call `textfuntion()`, this function will display text's width and height. when I click `button2` again same `textfuntion()` will be called and text width and height will be displayed. Here when I click `button1` I see `getBBox().width` and `getBBox().width` is 0. If I click `button2` and I see `getBBox().width` and `getBBox().width` is 23 and 40 depends on the text.

Even though same function called by both buttons I get values only by `button2` not by `button1` what would be the problem?.

**UPDATE:** I have checked `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` of the `text` element, these values also 0 untill I click `button2`. On click of `button1` gives 0 for both `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight`.

Comment: if possible, make a demo on jsfiddle. thanks

Comment: the example from [This link](http://jsfiddle.net/aD6ZS/) is working fine, but when I put the same code in my application is not working. I know it is difficult to answer without me explain entire application, but it is hard for me to explain my application. all I need is have label with dynamically created text.

Comment: Check if the node is displayed. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744176/getbbox-and-getcomputedtextlength-once-working-once-not