# getBBox() and getComputedTextLength() once working, once not

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, typescript

I am creating charts with d3.js+svg+javscript/typescript. I need to know length of texts to append it in proper places.

I am using/was trying to use functions getBBox()  and getComputedTextLength(), but...  getBBoX works only when I am generating chart for the first time (for second time and next it returns 0), while getComputedTextLength() works... just sometimes. From that what I read the problem could be that svgtext is not generated before I am trying to read its width/height.

```
    export function ReturnWidthOfText(text1, rotate, fontSize, someSVGGroup , fontName)
{

    var tempText;
    if (rotate == true) 
    {
        tempText = someSVGGroup.append("svg:text")
            .attr("id", "lolo")
            .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
            .style("font-family", fontName)
            .attr("transform", "rotate(270)")
            .text(text1);
    }
    else
    {
        tempText = someSVGGroup.append("svg:text")
            .attr("id", "lolo")
            .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
            .style("font-family", fontName)
            .text(text1);
    }

    var width = tempText.getComputedTextLength();

    document.getElementById("lolo").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("lolo"))

    return width;
}    


    export function ReturnSizeOfText(text1, rotate,  fontSize, someSVGGroup, fontName) {

    //let svgText = document.getElementById("lolo");
    var tempText;

    if (rotate == "Yes") 
    {
        tempText = someSVGGroup.append("svg:text")
            .attr("id", "lolo")
            .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
            .style("font-family", fontName)
            .attr("transform", "rotate(270)")
            .text(text1);
    }
    else
    {
        tempText = someSVGGroup.append("svg:text")
            .attr("id", "lolo")
            .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
            .style("font-family", fontName)
            .text(text1);
    }

    let size;
    size = { Width: 0, Height: 0 };
    let element: any = document.getElementById("lolo");
    let bbox = element.getBBox();

    //console.log(text.node().getBBox());
    size.Width = bbox.width;
    size.Height = bbox.height;


    //var width = tempText.getComputedTextLength();

    document.getElementById("lolo").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("lolo"))

    return size;


}
```

Could anyone advise how to improve those functions to work properly?
As I am preparing "App for Office" I am interested mainly in solution for IE and Edge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG -> getBBox fails but only half the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690374/svg-getbbox-fails-but-only-half-the-time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found an answer. It was returning 0s, because it returns good results only when svg/html block is visible, while when I was trying to regenerate chart it was hidden.